Por que utilizar o "_" no nome do atributo quando definimos uma propriedade em Python?
Estou com uma dificuldade conceitual de entendimento sobre os getters e setters usando property.
No exemplo abaixo:
class Pessoa:
  def __init__(self, valor):
    self._nome = valor

  @property
  def nome(self):
    return self._nome

  @nome.setter
  def nome(self, valor):
    self._nome = valor

p1 = Pessoa('joao')
print(p1.nome) # joao

Definindo o atributo da classe como _nome, esse exemplo funcionou. Entretanto, a minha dúvida é o que ocorre quando eu escrevo da seguinte maneira:
class Pessoa:
  def __init__(self, valor):
    self.nome = valor

  @property
  def nome(self):
    return self.nome

  @nome.setter
  def nome(self, valor):
    self.nome = valor

p1 = Pessoa('joao')

Este código dá erro:
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-1a47c7f926e7> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 p1 = Pessoa('joao')
      2 print(p1.nome)

2 frames
... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-13-e2e2fa7896b9> in nome(self, valor)
      9   @nome.setter
     10   def nome(self, valor):
---> 11     self.nome = valor

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Eu não estou entendendo a dinâmica do uso do _ ao definir os atributos da classe. Quando eu faço a declaração da forma abaixo, também funciona:
class Pessoa:
  def __init__(self, valor):
    self.nome = valor

  @property
  def nome(self):
    return self._nome

  @nome.setter
  def nome(self, valor):
    self._nome = valor

p1 = Pessoa('joao')
print(p1.nome)
joao

Acho que está me fugindo algum conceito sobre o uso do _ na definição dos atributos.

"....conceito sobre o uso do _ na definição dos atributos..." ??????? O _ é só um caractere, existe um acordo de damas e cavalheiros entre os programadores python onde convencionou-se que dentro de uma classe identificadores iniciados com _ são privados, mas esse acordo não é honrado por nenhum compilador e então repito, o _ é só um caractere. O que acontece é que fazerself.nome = valor dentro setter você chama o próprio setter que tem uma linha self.nome = valor que  chama o próprio setter que tem uma linha self.nome = valor que chama o próprio setter que tem uma linha..........

Apenas complementando a ótima resposta do @AugustoVasques, esta definição pode ser encontrada na PEP 8, na secção "Descriptive: Naming Styles"  https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

Acho importante explicitar que a variável poderia ser xnome, qqcoisanome, joselito etc - o importante é apenas a grafia não ser igual á da propriedade já existente. Considerando o que o AugustoVasques e @Confundir disseram nos comments sobre convenção, claro.

Vamos por partes...

Primeiro vamos fazer um exemplo mais simples, sem _nome, somente com o decorador @property:
class Pessoa:
    @property
    def nome(self):
        return 'Fulano'

p1 = Pessoa()
print(p1.nome) # Fulano

Ou seja, @property faz com que nome se torne uma propriedade. Ao acessar p1.nome, o método nome será executado. Neste exemplo, ele sempre retorna a mesma string "Fulano".
Agora vamos acrescentar o setter:
class Pessoa:
    @property
    def nome(self):
        return 'Fulano'

    @nome.setter
    def nome(self, valor):
        print(f'chamando nome.setter: {valor}')

p1 = Pessoa()
print(p1.nome) # Fulano
p1.nome = 'abc' # chama o setter (no caso, vai imprimir "chamando nome.setter: abc")
print(p1.nome) # Fulano

Ao executar p1.nome = 'abc', na verdade faz com que o método definido em def nome(self, valor) seja executado. Ou seja, é o mesmo que chamar este método passando o valor como argumento. Por isso o resultado é que ele imprima a mensagem "chamando nome.setter: abc".
Depois eu chamo o getter de novo, e ele retorna a mesma string "Fulano" novamente.

Agora voltando ao seu exemplo:
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.nome = valor

    @property
    def nome(self):
        return self._nome

    @nome.setter
    def nome(self, valor):
        self._nome = valor

p1 = Pessoa('Fulano')
print(p1.nome) # Fulano
p1.nome = 'abc'
print(p1.nome) # abc


Primeiro, Pessoa('Fulano') chama o construtor (o método __init__) passando a string 'Fulano' como argumento.
Dentro do construtor, é feita uma chamada ao setter.
No setter, o campo _nome é setado com o valor da string 'Fulano'
Ao chamar o getter, ele retorna o valor de _nome, que é a string 'Fulano'
Depois eu chamo o setter, mudando o valor de _nome, e chamo o getter de novo, para ver que ele foi modificado


E por que dá erro se eu trocar _nome para nome? Vejamos:
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.nome = valor

    @property
    def nome(self):
        return self.nome

    @nome.setter
    def nome(self, valor):
        self.nome = valor

p1 = Pessoa('Fulano') # RecursionError


Primeiro, Pessoa('Fulano') chama o construtor (o método __init__) passando a string 'Fulano' como argumento.
Dentro do construtor, é feita uma chamada ao setter.
Dentro do setter, é feita outra chamada ao mesmo setter (sim, self.nome = valor chama o setter, lembra?)
Dentro do setter, é feita outra chamada ao mesmo setter (sim, self.nome = valor chama o setter, lembra?)
e assim vai, indefinidamente, até estourar o limite da pilha de recursão

Quando um método/função chama ele mesmo, isso é chamado de recursão. Há um limite para a quantidade de chamadas recursivas, e quando este estoura, ocorre o RecursionError.
Isso não ocorre quando você usa _nome, porque aí não é o setter que está sendo chamado.
E na verdade funcionaria com qualquer outro nome diferente de nome. É que existe uma convenção de se usar _ no início do nome para indicar campos privados, mas a princípio você poderia trocar por qualquer outro nome.

E complementando a outra resposta, é interessante ver também "Como o @property funciona".

Obrigado pela resposta bem completa. A recorrência ficou bem clara. A outra dúvida que eu estava (usar no construtor o atributo self.nome ou self._nome) eu consegui entender enquanto fui testando esses conceitos no collab e entendi a lógica. Usando self.nome no construtor, ele já invoca o setter e o setter criar o atributo _nome. Ao usar self._nome no construtor, ele não invoca o setter, mas criar um atributo _nome que será acessado via getter ou modificado via setter. Em ambos os casos, o atributo da classe sempre será _nome. Entendi tudo agora. Obrigado mais uma vez.

@juliusczm Essa de qual usar no construtor é uma questão desde que existe a propriedade. Muitos dizem que o melhor é definir diretamente o atributo com um valor de estado válido, sem passar pelo setter (e inclusive muitas IDEs recomendam que isso seja feito e reclamam quando o atributo não é definido no construtor); enquanto muitos outros dizem que a responsabilidade de validar se é um estado válido é do setter e portanto o construtor deve utilizá-lo. Não existe uma regra, use a que mais fazer sentido para a sua solução.

Será mais fácil entender se alterarmos a forma como está fazendo, mas sem alterar o funcionamento em si.
Ao invés de declarar uma propriedade utilizando o decorador @property iremos defini-lo utilizando como classe mesmo.
class Pessoa
  def get_nome(self):
    return self.nome

  def set_nome(self, valor):
    self.nome = valor

  nome = property(get_nome, set_nome)

Isso funciona exatamente da mesma forma como fez com o decorador, mas deixa mais claro que quando você define uma propriedade com nome nome você criará o atributo nome na sua classe. Python não faz distinção de nomes do que é atributo do que é método.
É interessante comentar também que a classe property implementa o protocolo descritor. Leia mais sobre esse protocolo na documentação oficial Descriptor Guide. Esse protocolo implementa através de "métodos mágicos" a forma como o objeto deverá se comportar quando tiver seu valor acessado ou atribuído ou mesmo removido.
Quando você nomeia o atributo como nome também, o Python irá interpretar ele como sendo a própria propriedade, então o método getter irá retornar ela mesma e o setter entrará em recurção infinita porque irá fazer que ela é ela mesma.
De forma mais clara seria basicamente fazer:
@nome.setter
def set_nome(self, value):
  self.set_nome(value)

Aqui fica bem mais claro a recursão.
Por isso o atributo associado a uma propriedade comumente recebe o _ no início, apenas para distinguir o que é a propriedade do que é o atributo real da classe.

Como já foi aqui esclarecido, ao usar-se
@property
def nome(self):
    return self.nome

@nome.setter:
def nome(self, nome):
    self.nome = nome


O setter de nome acaba chamando-se a si mesmo causando um loop infinito. 
Uma das soluções para isto seria criar uma variável "privada" que como exemplo vamos usar _nome 
Usando-se o seguinte código
@property
def nome(self):
    return self._nome

@nome.setter
def nome(self, nome):
    self._nome = nome

Fazendo isto, você cria uma variável "privada" chamada _nome que recebe o valor do atributo nome passado ao setter da variável nome
assim evitando que o setter de nome chame-se a si mesmo ao tentar definir um valor a si.
